# How to get the minimum size of a treeview control that avoids scroll bars?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a dialog with a tree view inside it, and would like to have the dialog re-size itself automatically when the tree is expanded or collapsed to avoid scroll bars or excessive space.

In order to do so I need some way of finding the "desired" size of the tree view, i.e., the smallest size large enough to avoid displaying scroll bars.

Any suggestions?

Edit: So, I'm halfway there. I can determine the height by counting the number of visible items and multiplying by `TreeView_GetItemHeight`. I still have no idea how to find the width, however...

Comment: Use TreeView_GetItemRect() for every node.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately `TreeView_GetItemRect` only works for items that are visible within the client area, and so is not useful to determine how big to make the treeview to make the items visible.

Comment: You cannot get the size of an invisible node.  So use it *after* you made it visible.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks, I figured out what was going wrong: I was using `TVN_ITEMEXPANDING` rather than `TVN_ITEMEXPANDED`, so the item hadn't expanded yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite perfect (it doesn't seem possible to have `TreeView_GetItemRect` horizontally include the whole line up to the end of text), but the following works great for my use case with disabled horizontal scrolling.

```
void Dialog::getDimensionTreeView(unsigned int id,
                                  unsigned int &width, unsigned int &height) {
    HWND item = GetDlgItem((HWND)_hwnd, id);
    if(!item) {
        width = 0;
        height = 0;
        return;
    }

    RECT area = { };
    HTREEITEM node = TreeView_GetRoot(item);
    do {
        RECT rc;
        LPRECT prc = &rc;
        // Ideally this would use `fItemRect`=FALSE, but that seems
        // to just return the current width of the treeview control.
        TreeView_GetItemRect(item, node, prc, TRUE);
        if(rc.left < area.left) area.left = rc.left;
        if(rc.right > area.right) area.right = rc.right;
        if(rc.top < area.top) area.top = rc.top;
        if(rc.bottom > area.bottom) area.bottom = rc.bottom;
    } while((node = TreeView_GetNextVisible(item, node)));
    width = area.right - area.left;
    height = area.bottom - area.top;
}
```

Thanks to Hans Passant for putting me on the right track.